# Entities from one to many relationship out of date with JPA/EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink, one-to-many

I have been working with JPA/EclipseLink for a year but I still have a problem understanding how it updates the managed entities when you add an entity in a one to many relationship.

For example, in my application I have projects which have several analysis inside. The project is first created and then the user can add analysis inside (one by one). My problem is: **what is the proper way to persist a new analysis (and same question for deleting one from the project) so that the analysis is well managed and the project is updated?**

Here is the project class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project implements Serializable {


/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/** The id project. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_project", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idProject;

/** The project name. */
@Column(name="project_name", nullable=false, length=50)
private String projectName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Analysis
/** The analysis. */
@OneToMany(mappedBy="project", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Analysis> analysis;

    ... other stuff
}
```

The Analysis class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="analyz")
public class Analysis implements Serializable{

/** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/** The id analysis. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_analysis", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idAnalysis;

/** The analysis name. */
@Column(name="analysis_name", nullable=false, length=50)
private String analysisName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Project
/** The project. */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_project", nullable=false)
private Project project;

   ... other stuff
}
```

The function I use for creating a new analysis:

```
public void createAnalysis(String name, int projectId) {

    Project project = daoProject.findById(projectId);

    Analysis analysis = new Analysis();
    analysis.setProject(project);

    analysis.setNameAnalysis(name);
    project.getAnalysis().add(analysis);
    daoProject.update(project);// I also tried daoAnalysis.create(analysis)
}
```

If I update the project, my project object is up-to-date with a new analysis but the analysis object does not have its ID...
If I persist the analysis by itself, when I retrieve the project object later, using its id, I don't get the updates on it and the new analysis is not in the project.

Same problem for deleting an analysis: should I update the project or remove the analysis alone (using "daoAnalysis.delete(analysis)")?

To give all the elements, here is my generic DAO (daoProject and daoAnalysis are instances of it):

```
 public class BasicDAO<T extends Serializable> implements IDao<T> {

/** The class of the entity to be manipulated. */
private Class<T> entityClass;

/** The entity manager factory. */
protected EntityManagerFactory emf;

/**
 * Instantiates a new abstract dao.
 *
 * @param c the class
 */
public BasicDAO(Class<T> c) {
    entityClass = c;
}

/**
 * Gets the emf.
 *
 * @return the emf
 */
public EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
    return emf;
}

/**
 * Sets the emf.
 *
 * @param emf the new emf
 */
public void setEmf(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}


public T findById(Integer id){
    T result = null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    if (id == null || id < 1)
        throw new PersistenceException("Id may not be null or negative");
    result = em.find(entityClass, id);
    em.close();
    return result;
}


public void create(T entity){
    System.out.println("Create de AbstractDAO");
    //First we check that the object is not alreadt in database
    List<T> list = findAll();
    if(list.contains(entity)){
        return;
    }
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if(entity == null)
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to persist may not be null");//throw Persistence exception
    em.persist(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}


public void delete(T entity){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    if (entity == null)
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to delete may not be null");

    em.remove(em.merge(entity));
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}


public T update(T entity){
    T result = null;
    if (entity == null){
        System.out.println("Exception : entity to update may not be null");
        throw new PersistenceException("Entity to update may not be null");
    }
    List<T> list = findAll();
    int numberEquals = 0;
    for(T elem : list){
        if(elem.equals(entity))
            numberEquals++;
    }
    if(numberEquals>1)
        return null;
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(entity);
    result = entity;
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

I assume your update method uses merge on project.  Merge takes objects and returns tha managed instance with the changes merged in.  If the object is new, it will create a new managed instance to reflect the data - this is likely why your version of the analysis doesn't have it's ID set.  You need to use the manged instance returned dorm the merge process rather than what was passed in.

Persist can be used directly on a new analysis, but you still need to merge any changes made to project for them to show up in the cache.  So you would persist the analysis and then merge project.  More code, but it can be more efficient since the provider doesn't need to check if analysis exists already on the merge call.  Persist makes the instance passed in the managed entity, so it will have the ID set.

Answer (score 0):

If you face difficulties updating one-to-many relationship entities then keep in mind these 3 steps:

1. mention `cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true` in `@OneToMany` list, example:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentEntity",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   private List< ChildEntity > childEntityList;
   ```
2. always perform update from many side (the parent entity where list of child entity listed).
3. call `getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Class)` after every update to clear the cache.